# How is a differential like V = $\delta_x+x\delta_y$ a vector field?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

How is a differential like V = $\delta_x+x\delta_y$ a vector field?

I mean, a vector field should assign to every point a vector. Perhaps if something is being parameterized and so these differential operators have something to operate on I could understand.

How does V = $\delta_x+x\delta_y$ assign a vector (direction and magnitude) to every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a general manifold, one uses the partial derivatives of a coordinate chart to define vector fields.
On $\mathbb R^2$ one can simply choose the identity map.

In this coordinate chart, your vector field $V$ is a map
\begin{align}
V:\mathbb R^2&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2 \\
(x,y)&\longmapsto(1,x)
\end{align}